# Why PayPal redirects to home page instead of payment page?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I got a huge problem with my PayPal e-commerce payment system.
The users cannot proceed to payment, because they are redirected to the PayPal home page instead of the payment page.

I can reproduce the problem easily, by typing the payment url twice in the browser, for instance [this one](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr&cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=AP-2X806825AL842552D&lc=fr_CA) (valide for 3 hours)

The first time, the payment page can appears, and the second time it will be the home page. The home page can appears the first time too. It looks like random.

Does someone know something about that problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the first ampersand (`&`) in the URL to a question mark (`?`) -- so that it's `https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_ap-payment&paykey=...` instead.

Comment: Exactly... Thanks!!